# C# how to get all XML Value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I've got an XML file

```
<forecast>
<time from="2020-04-05T03:00:00" >
<temperature unit="celsius" value="9.46" min="8.84" max="9.46"/>
<clouds value="overcast clouds" all="96" unit="%"/>
</time>
<time from="2020-04-05T09:00:00">
<temperature unit="celsius" value="9.53" min="9.22" max="9.53"/>
<clouds value="scattered clouds" all="49" unit="%"/>
</time>
</forecast>
```

working with c#

```
foreach (var npc in doc.Descendants("forecast"))
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[]
    {
        (DateTime) npc.Descendants("time").First().Attribute("from"),
        (string) npc.Descendants("temperature").First().Attribute("value"),
        (string) npc.Descendants("clouds").First().Attribute("value")
    });
}
```

I got first value only,what is the method for looping all value ?

Answer (score -1):

Try using below code to get all node list:

```
    XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/forecast/time");
```

Then loop through it.

Comment: He's using `XDocument` object model, not `XmlDocument`.

Comment: i don't get it .
may you elaborate it ....
thank for cooperation